# Load balanced WCF service unavailability - Hosted as Windows Service and listen at 443 over TCP

Tags: c#, wcf, load-balancing, internal-load-balancer

We have developed couple of WCF services for our application. From our web application, we are able to reach those end points through individual server. When we try to reach them through load balancer we are getting following error:

```
There was no endpoint listening at net.tcp://<IP>:443/<Service API> that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionUpgradeHelper.DecodeFramingFault(ClientFramingDecoder decoder, IConnection connection, Uri via, String contentType, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
```

Additional information:

- WCF service hosted as windows service
- WCF service listing on 443 port
- TCP is the communication protocol between web and service

Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem. i managed to solve it by adding this to my config file at server side:

```
  <system.net>
<connectionManagement>
  <add address="*" maxconnection="500" />
</connectionManagement>
```

the default value is 2. for more information you can read this:[scale up WCF service](https://codewala.net/2014/10/14/simple-steps-scale-up-wcf-drastically/)